# Do each of the manifestations of the devas have their own jiva?

Tags: gods, atma, jiva

There are 33 devas but thousands of thousands of manifestations of these 33 devas. Do each of these manifestations have their own jiva, or do they share there jiva with other manifestations of the same type?

Comment: No, a deva has only on jiva. A manifestation of a deva means that their consciousness has entered that manifestation. And because their consciousness entered it, the deva can control that manifestation through their own will.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Which scripture or scholar are you basing your statement off of?

Comment: I follow Ramanujacharya's school of Sri Vaishnavism.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Is this question ever answered anywhere by Ramanujacharya or his followers? Do they ever say a deva only has one jiva?

Comment: Yes they do, and acharyas other than Ramanujacharya share the same belief. A "deva" is a position that a jivatma attains after doing a lot of good karma. And a "manifestation" of a deva is an incarnation of a deva. For example, Aniruddha is a manifestation of Narayana, but Aniruddha is still Narayana because the soul is the same. What makes a manifestation or incarnation is that the *consciousness* of the Jivatma enters that manifestation or body.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Do any devas exist other than the 33 named in scripture?

Comment: @Ikshvaku So there can be only one Indra at a time?

Comment: "So there can be only one Indra at a time?" - Correct, there can only be one Indra in each universe (a universe consists of the 14 lokas). There are several universes though.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Is there any scholar saying this?

Comment: Yes, the Puranas mention it, as well as the scholars in the vaishnava lineages. I think it's a generic Hindu belief.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Do you have the Puranic quotes saying that there can only be one jiva for each of the 33 classes of deva at a time?

Comment: "Do you have the Puranic quotes saying that there can only be one jiva for each of the 33 classes of deva at a time?" - No, but I have quote from scholars who have studied the Puranas. I don't think a Purana would say that, since it doesn't seem like a Puranic quote. That is more like an analysis of what the Puranas say about Gods.